# Objective-C : containsObject is always returning NO

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand why, the containsObject method seems to always return NO, here is my method :

```
-(void)addTockens:(NSString *)tockens
{
    if ([tockens length] == 2 && ![self.tockensArray containsObject:tockens]) {
        [self.tockensArray addObject:tockens];
        NSLog(@"Added");
    }
}
```

And here is what I am doing :

```
TADIgnoringConstraint *ignorer = [TADIgnoringConstraint new];
[ignorer addTockens:@"[]"];
[ignorer addTockens:@"[]"];
```

I am getting two "Added" in the console even if it shouldn't do that the second time I am trying to add "[]" since "[]" is already in the table.

Comment: Thats not returning no. This does: `[tockens length] == 2`

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your question if length is really 2?

Comment: Id guess it is tokens. no ck ;)

Comment: Is an array absolutely necessary?  If you need to be sure the object isn't already in a collection before you add it to the collection, then the collection you probably need to be using is `NSMutableSet`.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are not creating an instance for `self.tockensArray`, so everything you ask the `tockensArray` returns `nil` (which is `NO`).

Be sure that you initialise `self.tockensArray` in your `init` method.

Comment: tockensArray is declared in the interface file like this :  
@property NSMutableArray *tockensArray;

Comment: In fact I am new to Objective-C and I don't understand why do I need to initialise self.tockenArray since I already declared it in the interface ?

Comment: Declaration just says you want somewhere to store a pointer to an instance, but it doesn't create (instantiate) an instance, that is something separate, then you can store the pointer to that instance in your @property

Comment: Declaring a property in the interface does only that.  The property is `nil` until initialized; e.g. `_tockensArray = [NSMutableArray array];` or the like...

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Being new to Objective-C isn't an excuse.  Declaration alone isn't acceptable in any OOP language.  They all need to be initialized before they can be used.  The difference is that in a lot of others, calling a method on an uninitialized object usually results in a crash.  It doesn't change the fact that in any OOP language, objects must be initialized before they're ready to be used.

Comment: @Wain Ok thank you, and in my case, where is my init method ? Because I am just creating my object with the new method and then using the addTocken method.

Comment: Create the `init` method if it doesn't exist

Comment: @Wain Is it a good alternative to see if self.tockensArray is equal or not to nil directly in my method, and if equal to nil set it with an empty array ?

Comment: Not really, the object should configure itself appropriately before use